# Given the function $f(x)=\left(3x^{\frac75}\!-\!\frac{\pi}x\right)\!\cdot\!\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2\!-\!x\right)$. Calculate $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Given the function $f(x)=\left(3x^{\frac75}\!-\!\dfrac{\pi}x\right)\!\cdot\!\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}2\!-\!x\right)$. Calculate the limit $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)\;.$

So I started by using the definition of the derivative that

$$f'(x_{0})=\lim_{x \to x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_0}$$

after doing that I tried to set $x_{0} = 0$ since then u get the limit to $x \to 0$, but the problem is that $f(0)$ is not defined, because if I substitute $x=0$ in the function I get $f(0)=(0-\infty)\cdot{}0$ which is undefined, same goes for $f'(0)$

Now I can't seem to find the solution, so I'm asking the question here

Comment: If $f$ is undefined at some point then $f'$ is also undefined at that point.

Comment: Split it into two terms.

Comment: Remember the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ when $x \to 0$.

Comment: Don't use the definition of the derivative on $f$ but on $\sin$.

Comment: Lynx_s, what do you want to calculate? $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$ or $f’(0)$?

Comment: @Angelo I need to calculate the limit but I thought using the definition of derivative to then manipulate it to then get something of the limit of f(x) with x going to 0, I tried this since this question is asked in the chapter of differentiation so I assumed we had to use the definition or derivative in some way

Comment: @geetha290krm do you mean the limit I proposed or?

Comment: @Cactus Sorry I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: @lynx_s, if you want to know what Cactus means, read my answer and tell me what you think about it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the definition of derivative in order to calculate your limit, you can proceed in the following way:

$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)&= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(3x^{\frac75}-\frac{\pi}x\right)\!\cdot\!\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)=\\[3pt]&=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(3 x^{\frac75}-\frac{\pi}x\right)\!\cdot\!\sin(x)=\\[3pt]&=3\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(x^{\frac75}\!\sin(x)\right)-\pi\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}x=\\&=3\!\cdot\!0-\pi\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}=\\[3pt]&=-\pi\!\cdot\!\big[D\sin(x)\big]\bigg|_{x=0}=-\pi\!\cdot\!\big[\cos(x)\big]\bigg|_{x=0}=\\[3pt]&=-\pi\!\cdot\!\cos(0)=-\pi\!\cdot\!1=-\pi\;.\end{align}$

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks a lot this just gave some new insight on how to solve something like this, tricky tho, I needed the answer because it was an exam question in 2015-2016, there is also a extra question, where they ask how the function is continuous on R if we extend the function, I'm supposing we could do that by defining f(x) as a Piecewise function where f(x) = (3x/..)sin(x) if x < 0 and x > 0 and f(x) = $-\pi$ where x = 0?

Comment: @lynx_s, yes, you can extend the function $f(x)$ by defining it as a piecewise function in the way you did. So you will get a function continuous on all $\Bbb R\,.$ It is correct what you said.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\,\,\sim\,\,x$ when $x\to 0$. So:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(3x^{\frac{7}{5}}-\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\cdot x=\lim_{x\to 0}3x^{\frac{12}{5}}-\pi=-\pi$$